# need quick small help in mariadb stored procedure query-

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, count, sum, mariadb

I need help in mariadb stored procedure query-

Need to get sum of `(COUNT(ID)*AvgWeight) from table A group by AvgWeight`

without using temptable insert

I have `ID` and `avgweight`

```
1 55
2 55
3 45
4 45
5 45
6 60
7 60
```

So I need `sum(2into55+3into45+2into60)` as single value

Answer (score 2):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select sum(avgweight * cnt) res
from (
    select avgweight, count(*) cnt
    from mytable
    group by avgweight
) t
```

Comment: great this works! now I need to update another table with this single value but mytable date needs to be less than equal to second table date so update secondtable set totalavgweight=select sum(avgweight * cnt) res
from (
    select avgweight, count(*) cnt
    from mytable where mytable.date<=secondtable.date
    group by avgweight
) t

Comment: But when I try where clause with date from secondtable it does not recognize it

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a query on a subquery. The needed subquery you describe looks something like this I presume:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, AvgWeight FROM A GROUP BY AvgWeight
```

I'm not quite sure what exactly you want, but I'm assuming summing of the AvgWeight? You should be able to adapt the following query to your needs:

```
SELECT SUM(AvgWeight)
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, AvgWeight FROM A GROUP BY AvgWeight)
```

Comment: Its giving me syntax error in mariadb. Thank you for your help.